# Add/attach a UserID based on Session PHP

Tags: php, variables, session

Looking to add a UserID based on session variable to this post method.

I can display the diary posts based on the Session ID but want to actually add the User's ID into the corresponding table everytime an entry is posted.

I've included pictures of the database below and the Insert Query that already adds posts.

The diary and tblUseraccount are already linked using foreign keys

PHP functions

```html
<?php
if(session_id() == '') {
 session_start();
        
}



if(!isset($_SESSION['myEmail'])){ //if login in session is not set
    header("Location: login.php");
}

 if (!isset($_SESSION['myEmail'])) {
  echo"  <a href='login.php'";
   }
   else {
             $myFName = $_SESSION['userFirstName'];
          }
```

The code I want to insert the UserID too

```html
<?php
// post_add.php
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    include 'mysql.php';
    if(mysql_safe_query('INSERT INTO posts (title,body,date,) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)', $_POST['title'], $_POST['body'], time()))
        echo 'Entry posted. <a href="post_view.php?id='.mysql_insert_id().'">View</a>';
    else
        echo mysql_error();
}
?>
```

The mysql.php portion

```html
<?php
// mysql.php
function mysql_safe_string($value) {
    $value = trim($value);
    if(empty($value))           return 'NULL';
    elseif(is_numeric($value))  return $value;
    else                        return "'".mysql_real_escape_string($value)."'";
}
function mysql_safe_query($query) {
    $args = array_slice(func_get_args(),1);
    $args = array_map('mysql_safe_string',$args);
    return mysql_query(vsprintf($query,$args));
}
function redirect($uri)
{
    if (!headers_sent())
    {    
        header('Location: '.$uri);
        exit;
        }
    else
        {  
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'window.location.href="'.$uri.'";';
        echo '</script>';
        echo '<noscript>';
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$uri.'" />';
        echo '</noscript>'; exit;
    }
}
@mysql_connect('localhost','######','#######');
@mysql_select_db('######');
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bQ24.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHqp3.png)

Comment: Also, please use mysqli or pdo instead of mysql, as it's been deprecated

Comment: Please check my answer John and get back to me if you don't understand anything

Comment: @edisoni.1337 it's displaying Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to set UserId in session
when you make the user login you can add the user id in session like you have added `userFirstName`

After that you can just start sessions in your file and then get the userId from session when you want to insert a post

```
session_start();

if(!empty($_POST)) {
    include 'mysql.php';

    $userId = $_SESSION['UserID']; //or whatever is your key in session where you store the user id

    if(mysql_safe_query('INSERT INTO posts (title,body,date,UserID) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)', $_POST['title'], $_POST['body'], time(), $userId)){
        echo 'Entry posted. <a href="post_view.php?id='.mysql_insert_id().'">View</a>';
    }else{
        echo mysql_error();
    }
}
```

Also I noticed that your are using `mysql_query` to run your queries. You should use `mysqli_query` or `PDO` because `mysql_query` is **deprecated** in PHP 5.5 and it is **removed** in PHP 7.

You can read more in php page [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: Because I forgot to add '%s' at VALUES. @John please check again updated answer